# I cannot post using request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, http-post

My problem i that I get an error telling me I can't make post request. I use the insertDocuments function to insert messages into a database. I am attempting to make a promise oriented version of the ['mongolab-data-api'](https://github.com/gamontal/mongolab-data-api) node.js module. I apologize if my question is confusing

```
//This is a function in a class that handles all mlab related things
var rp = require('request-promise')
var insertDocuments = options => {
    if (!options.database || !options.collectionName || !options.documents) throw new Error('Database name, Collection Name, and Document(s) are required')
    var opt = {
        uri: `https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/${options.database}/collections`,
        qs: {
            apiKey: this.apiKey

        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            documents: options.documents
        },
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        },
        json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
    };
    return rp(opt)
}

var options = {
    database: 'lexybase',
    collectionName: 'evy-history',
    documents: msg
}
insertDocuments(options)
```

I get this error:
Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 405 - {"message":"POST not allowed."}

```
at new StatusCodeError (/rbd/pnpm-volume/b50cbf1c-9de1-48a8-8200-48301efdd80c/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/request-promise-core/1.1.1/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)

at Request.plumbing.callback (/rbd/pnpm-volume/b50cbf1c-9de1-48a8-8200-48301efdd80c/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/request-promise-core/1.1.1/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)

at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/b50cbf1c-9de1-48a8-8200-48301efdd80c/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/request-promise-core/1.1.1/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)

at Request.self.callback (/rbd/pnpm-volume/b50cbf1c-9de1-48a8-8200-48301efdd80c/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/request/2.88.0/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)

at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)

at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)

at Request.<anonymous> (/rbd/pnpm-volume/b50cbf1c-9de1-48a8-8200-48301efdd80c/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/request/2.88.0/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)

at emitOne (events.js:116:13)

at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)

at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/rbd/pnpm-volume/b50cbf1c-9de1-48a8-8200-48301efdd80c/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/request/2.88.0/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)

at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)

at emitNone (events.js:111:20)

at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)

at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)

at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)

at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

Edit: As it turns out, the problem was that collectionName need3d to be specified and it shoul have been

```
body:  options.documents
```

instead of

```
body: {
    documents:options.documents
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the collection name in **uri**:

uri: `https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/${options.database}/collections`

should be:

uri: `https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/${options.database}/collections/{collectionName}`

just change the *collectionName*

405 is returned from [mongolab API](https://docs.mlab.com/data-api/)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out there